# android smack 4.1 xmpp message receive and join room

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, message, smack

i developed one chat application using android smack 4.1 xmpp.

In that i having Mainly Two Problem :

**1) On Receiving Messages**

Everything working fine at time of chatting , other person message receive and send also , but after some interval message automatic sending to other but not receive from the another device.

While receive message from the another device i getting SMCK-RECV log like

```
D/SMACK: RECV (2): <message from='37croom@conference.mydata.com/jacson##0123456@mydata.com/resorcesname' to='jacson##0123456@mydata.com/resorcesname' xml:lang='en' id='ohV1J-77' type='groupchat'><body>helo</body></message>
```

But not call receive message portion. It not happen every time , all working fine for some interval but after some messages it automatic just give above message but not call message receive body.

my message receive code is like following ;

```
  Constants.connection = connection;
    if (connection != null) {

        StanzaTypeFilter message_filter = new StanzaTypeFilter(Message.class);
        Constants.connection.addSyncStanzaListener(new StanzaListener() {
            @Override
            public void processPacket(Stanza packet) {

                Message message = (Message) packet;

               // all receive message handle here

         }, message_filter);

    }
```

**2) On join Room**

In that , i creating conference room by one person , sending request by another person  , accept and join the room.

After joining first time quick to accepting request , chatting not work to each other , but once i kill the application and join again and chat , then working fine ( except above issue 1 ).

So, please any one help me to solve out this both problem it very appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Please don't put multiple questions into the same post, create individual question posts instead.

Comment: i solve out my problem , i need to set some flag on connection change,and solve that

Comment: Care to share which flag this was?

Comment: I creating service to maintain connection alive and set flag true when connection alive .